# What causes unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error?

Tags: php, apache

I have a simple PHP script that keeps throwing this bizarre error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"string' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /script.php

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

    $api_key = "string"; // this line causes the error
    $payload = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $new_booking = json_decode($payload, true);
    $schedule_id = "123456";
    $schedule_link = "http://example.com";
    $passwd = "passwd";

    // email config
    $admin = [
        "name" => "Joe White", 
        "user" => "user@gmail.com", 
        "passwd" => "passwd"
    ];

    $max_time = 3; // hours
    $max_dist = 200; // miles

    /*
    Code goes on, but is commented out and therefore not included here
    */
    ?>
```

I saw somebody mention in another SO question that the issue might be CRLF line endings instead of CF, but I'm not sure.

Comment: And what line number does the error message tell you this error is on?

Comment: and have you shown the code for that particular line?

Comment: Stop using closing php tags (`?>`) at the end of files. They serve no purpose at all and cause trouble all the time.

Comment: Read the answers from PHP Parse/Syntax Errors, removed `?>`, no change.

Comment: @u_mulder In the answers you referred to, only simple typos and such are mentioned(incorrect concenation, mixed use of quotes, etc), I didn't find anything that'd help me, maybe you'd point it out.

Comment: Var_damp($payload); exit; chk what r u getting

Comment: I don't get anything.

Comment: If u r not getting any thing than how json decode will work?

Comment: OK, I figured out what was the issue, it was corrupted whitespace characters that can't be seen in an IDE. I don't want to make a new question, can anybody suggest a way to replace whitespace throughout the entire file?

Comment: php_strip_whitespace ( string $filename ); and let me knw if its work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101475/discussion-between-devpro-and-pancake-m0nster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up finding a solution myself, the error was due to some corrupt whitespace/linefeed characters, and since I didn't want to go through the entire file, I used those tools:

http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php
http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-white-spaces.php

This to verify the code: 
http://phpcodechecker.com

And this to beautify the code again:
http://www.cleancss.com/php-beautify/

**Make sure you remove all single line comments before the process.**